# Always display the current active profiles during the compile phase in Maven

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application which supports two profiles: dev and release. Obviously, the `dev` profile is used when working locally, and `release` profile is used by Jenkins as part of a CI/CD pipeline when actually deploying the application on a server.

**Profiles definition**

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>release</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>release</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

dev profile is activated by default since this is where developers spend most of their time: developing. I want them to specify the release profile when exporting the application somewhere else, but even better, delegate that task to Jenkins.

I just discovered the following command to see which profiles are active:

```
mvn help:active-profiles
```

So I can use this in my Jenkins pipeline script

```
mvn clean compile -Prelease help:active-profiles
```

That works. BUT, I wonder if there is a way to always run `help:active-profiles` goal during the compile phase, so all developers can clearly see which profile they are using.

Thank you

Comment: You can probably add an execution of the maven-help-plugin to the compile phase (in the pom.xml).

Comment: That's indeed my question :) Being quite new to Maven, I'm looking for guidance here. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add Maven Help Plugin as shown below:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>print-profile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>active-profiles</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

You can expect the log with the below message:

```
[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:2.2:active-profiles (print-profile) @ testProject ---
[INFO] 
Active Profiles for Project 'com.test.testProject:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT': 

The following profiles are active:

 - sonar (source: external)
 - release (source: external)
 - dev (source: com.test.testProject:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Using Eclipse Mars, I had a warning on the `execution` line, complaining about the following: `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:active-profiles (execution: print-profile, phase: compile)`. Looks to be a m2e glitch. I have clicked *Permanently mark goal active-profiles as ignored* and it works like it should.